# Sum of two difference sequences for consecutive numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, statistics, summation

**Problem Setting:**
If there are two difference sequences for consective integers $\{a_i \}_{i=1}^{n}$ and $\{b_i \}_{i=1}^{n}$ and they have a relationship that for any $i = 1,2,...,n$,

$$\delta = a_i - b_i, $$

and $\delta \in R$, how can we prove that

$$
\left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i y_i \right] \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i \right] - \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i \right]\left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2 \right] \neq \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i y_i \right] \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i \right] - \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i \right]\left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i^2 \right],
$$

where $y_i \in R$.

**Solved Attempt:** I tried to use proof by contradiction. Assuming that the above inequality is not hold so LHS = RHS, and plug in their relationship $\delta = a_i - b_i$, I can obtain

$$
\left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i y_i \right] \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i \right] - \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i \right]\left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2 \right] - \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i y_i \right] \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i \right] + \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i \right]\left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i^2 \right] = 0,
$$
after some calculation,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[-(n-1)n\delta^2 - \delta(2n-1)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i\right) + n \delta b_i \right]y_i = 0.
$$
**However, I didn't know how to continue this process. I am wondering how I can continue the proof or if I make any mistakes.**

Comment: Assume your final sum is correct. You can factor out $\delta.$ Then $\delta=0$ or the resulting sum is nul. It suffices to prove that the last one is impossible. Then you will have $\delta=0$ that means $a_i=b_i \forall i.$

Comment: I do not agree with your final result. I found
$$\delta\sum_{i=1}^n\left[nb_i-\sum_{j=1}^nb_j\right]y_i=0.$$
It is not clear what you want to (dis)prove, i.e. which quantifiers you put in front of your "LHS=RHS", but based on the previous result, you will easily conclude.

Comment: Hi @AnneBauval, I am wondering why we can conclude that the resulting sum is null.

Comment: Hi @user376343, I am wondering how can we show the resulting sum is not null.

Comment: I wrote that the sum is null exactly like you did (in your "solved attempt" with a proof by contradiction). I only corrected the calculation.